# KONY Preview using Emulator/Real Device

Tags: debugging, emulation, enterprise, temenos-quantum

I am new to Kony enterprise edition. I tried to run my app  using the Android emulator, always its showing unknown error (code 100-ref img), when I click OK, its closing app, I check the Support x86 devices in the settings. I install the apk using cmd, app installed but when I tried to open the app is showing the kony animation with launching icons. I tried to used local host in the kony app but no use. I am unable to guess the what is the error, and what went wrond. Requesting great help to run the app, and kony editor is taking very long period to build in at least in one platform (like android, desktop etc). Its killing my time for building app rather than development. Appreciate any tips to build as fast as possible and track errors.

[image: img]

Answer (score 1):

You can check the error's cause in DDMS(WINDOWS key+R -> DDMS -> press Enter). It should log the message for the cause of your error. Change the debug level to Error if there're too many messages.

As for making the build faster, it's mostly system-dependent, although you can make a few changes that might positively affect build times. Do this: go to your Kony studio's installation folder and find the eclipse.ini file. Open it and change the values of parameters like -Xmx and -XmsMaxPermSize to a higher number. e.g from -Xmx512m to -Xmx1024m. Now restart Kony studio. As an aside, a machine with a minimum of 8GB ram is recommended, with as less programs running as possible apart from Kony.

Lastly, and this is my opinion, Kony preview is basically a sub-optimal feature that's rarely used by any Kony dev I've ever met. You're better off running the final build on a device.